# Minimal package to install Qt Assistant

Tags: package-management, apt, deb, qt

We are using Qt Assistant as our help system for a custom application that will run on Ubuntu. In building the .deb package, I need to include a "Requires:" value that makes my package dependent on the Qt Assistant package being installed.

Right now I am using `qt4-dev-tools`, and it works, but this package is **huge** because it includes a whole lot of other tools that I don't need at all.

**What package do I require to get *only* Qt Assistant installed?**

*Also, if you could explain how you found the answer, I'd appreciate it. Poking around the Ubuntu package search isn't very efficient .. are there some `apt-get` commands that help here?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary assistant-qt4 is part of packages (oneiric) /1/ : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=assistant-qt4&mode=exactfilename&suite=oneiric&arch=any

- qt4-dev-tools
- qt4-bin-dbg

Both packages are build from the Qt sources (http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/oneiric/qt4-x11).

You could download the sources and add a new package: only-qt-assistant.

**Links:**
1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered an application package (Freecad) installed in Ubuntu 12.04 with this unresolved dependency and had to figure out what packages to install.  The help system needed to find `/bin/qtassisant` for its help system.  If you'd like to see for yourself, the version of the package freecad which I installed was `0.12.5284-dfsg-5ubuntu1`

To resolve this I installed `qt4-dev-tools` without recommends using this commandline:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install qt4-dev-tools
```

This provided qtassistant but not in the desired location or form, so I created a link.  Using a terminal I typed the following lines:

```
cd /bin
sudo ln -T /usr/bin/assistant-qt4 qtassistant
```

Finally the application's package did not include documentation, so I then typed:

```
sudo apt-get install freecad-doc
```

In addition my application (Freecad) needed and did not provide OPENGL (so I installed it), but that is outside the scope of this topic.